# Pandas - find pairs of rows with same integer values in at least two columns for a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with the efficient way how to select matching pairs of rows that have at least 2(3) common columns.
Sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    'C': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'D': [2, 7, 9, 8, 4]})
```

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Here only rows 0 and 1 have 2 common columns.

I have a working solution with numpy, but it fails when I get huge dataset as input (5 000 000 records) - obviously can't fit in memory 5*5 mln.

```
# Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array
np_array = df.to_numpy()   
# Find pairs of rows with same integers in at least two columns
matching_rows = np.sum(np_array[:, None] == np_array, axis=2) >= 2
np.fill_diagonal(matching_rows, False)
# Get the indices of the matching pairs
matching_pairs = np.argwhere(matching_rows)
# Filter out bidirectional links
matching_pairs = matching_pairs[matching_pairs[0:, 0] > matching_pairs[:, 1], :]
```

Appreciate any help regarding other solutions to select matching rows with any 2 common columns.

Comment: I have a stupid idea to create all pair combinations for columns and just loop through each combination and select duplicates..  But maybe there are some more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best approach but still you can try to implement. Assuming there are only four columns (A, B, C, and D), the condition is that there should be at least two matching columns. First, create combinations of columns, such as AB, AC, BC, and so on

```py
# creating sample dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,9,10),
'B':np.random.randint(1,9,10),
'C':np.random.randint(1,9,10),
'D':np.random.randint(1,9,10),})

# selecting 1st combination of columns i.e. AB
columns_to_check = ['A', 'B']
rows=df[df.duplicated(subset=columns_to_check,keep=False)].index.to_list()

print(rows)
[3, 6, 7] # These rows have same column values in col A & B

# To create combinations of these rows use itertools:
from itertools import combinations
pairs=[i for i in combinations(rows,2)]
print(pairs)
[(3, 6), (3, 7), (6, 7)] # Final output
```

Repeat the same process for other combinations as well. You may use for loop for that and itertools combinations() if there are many columns. Finally combine all the pairs and remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I mentioned in my comment to the question. But the fact is that it's still too large to process duplicates even with 2 columns..